# Can we compare apps on Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I would like that Ubuntu community discuss a little about which word processor is best to replace MSOffice Word and has the best compatibility with it - LibreOffice Writer, Abiword or Calligra Words. Can I make this question on Ask Ubuntu?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately no, [our FAQ page](https://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask) states:

> "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."

Asking a *specific question* about a *specific word processor* on the other hand is more than welcome. Example:

> "What compatibility issues will I encounter when opening MS Office documents in AbiWord?"

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will try to improve and shape my questions accordingly to that in the future.